# SQL Job unknown user or bad password

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We currently have a SQL Server 2012 job that fails and unable to figure out the problem.  The SQL job calls a SSIS package and if I run the package via Integration Services it runs successfully.  However when running the job it returns the following in Windows Event Viewer:

> SQL Error : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

SQL Job History Error:

> Error: 2017-04-28 09:43:40.17
>      Code: 0x00000006
>      Source: Create Temp Tables 1 
>      Description: The script returned a failure result.
>   End Error
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

There doesn't appear to be any information that helps resolve the issue.  We don't appear to have any proxies setup.  All other jobs that reference a SSIS package run successfully.

Comment: Have you tested the credentials?

Comment: I am unsure of what account it is trying to use?  Here is additional information.  **SQL Error : The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.**  The local Windows user account that is tied to SQL Server Agent, doesn't appear to be locked out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the error as there was a variable set in the package that was referencing a secondary server.  Changed the connection string and job is back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

To run SSIS package through JOB you need to set a password in the package
And when informing the package will be requested the password so that you can include in the job

Comment: Currently none of our SSIS packages have a password attached to them and they run successfully.  This is also the case with the job in question.  This job does reference a disk partition so it can read some files that will be imported into the database.  Permissions are granted properly to that folder.